# How to determine when SQL Server index statistics were last updated

Tags: sql-server

I want to check which index stats that hasn't been updated on tables that has page count of 500 mb and more.
I have this script:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS [ObjectName]
      ,[name] AS [StatisticName]
      ,STATS_DATE([object_id], [stats_id]) AS [StatisticUpdateDate]
FROM sys.stats
order by StatisticUpdateDate desc
```

Its not giving me all the info I want. Can someone be able to modify my script or show me how to get where I want to be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What info do you want exactly?

Comment: I want  index stats on tables that have a page count >= 500MB

Comment: Have you tried to do run  ```Update Statistics``` on the tables?

Comment: @ABHI Am doing an analyses first before updating the stats

Comment: What information are you expecting to see and what information is missing?

Comment: >>> page count >= 500MB <<< pages are pages ( 8Kb) Megabytes are Megabytes, 1Mb = 1024Kb. So do you want to filter out tables with >=  500 pages (4Mb) or >= 500 Mb?

Comment: @sepupic yes, thats what am looking for

Comment: so, 500 are Megabytes or pages?

Comment: @sepupic 500 will be pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for 500 pages even if I think 500Mb is more reasonable finter:

```
with cte as
(
select p.object_id,
       object_name(p.object_id) as obj,
       sum(total_pages) as tot_pages
from sys.partitions p join sys.allocation_units au 
        on au.container_id = p.hobt_id
group by p.object_id
)

SELECT c.* ,
       OBJECT_NAME(st.object_id) AS [ObjectName]
      ,[name] AS [StatisticName]
      ,STATS_DATE(st.[object_id], 
      [stats_id]) AS [StatisticUpdateDate]
FROM sys.stats st join cte c
        on st.object_id = c.object_id
where tot_pages >= 500;
```